# How to uninstall a .deb package?

Tags: package-management, deb

Suppose I download a .deb package from a website and install it. (I assume that when I double click the .deb file, the package is installed through a GUI that interfaces with dpkg right?)

How can I uninstall it?

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Manually installed packages appear in the Software Centre, along with all the others. Just search the software centre for your package and remove it there.

You may have to click on "Show N technical items"

[image]

Along with this, there are a few other methods:

Synaptic:

- Go to System → Administration → Synaptic Package Manager
- Click the *Status* button and select "Installed (local or obsolete)"
- Right click a package and select "mark for removal".
- Click the *Apply* button.

  This will have the benefit of listing all of your manually installed packages:

[image]

Command Line

- You can either use `sudo apt-get remove packagename` if you know the name of the package, or if you don't, search for it using `apt-cache search crazy-app` and then remove it using apt get
- You can also use `dpkg --remove packagename`.

[image: @GorgeEdison it's a security risk! :P @EveryoneElse, never mind I'm kidding :)]

This will also let you know if there are any unneeded packages left on your system, which were possibly installed as dependencies of your .deb package. Use `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of them.

Comment: `aerofs-installer-0` (aerofs.com) did not appear in U.S.C., only in the command line and in synaptic. Any idea why?

Comment: You can use "sudo apt purge package-name" to uninstall the package and the package's configuration as well.

Comment: +1 for pointing to synaptic - software center didn't show the app (Microsoft teams, maye because there is also another version from ubuntu??)

Comment: `dpkg --remove webex` helped me remove Cisco Webex. Thanks!

Answer (score 165):

To remove `package_name`, use `dpkg` with the `-r` (or `--remove`) flag:

```
sudo dpkg -r package_name
```

If you have to force-remove it, add `--force-all`:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all pkg_name
```

Use `-P` (or `--purge`) instead of `-r` if you want to remove the configuration files as well.

Comment: or `dpkg --purge package_name` to erase configuration files as well.

Answer (score 81):

Every solution here assumes you know or can find the name of the package, but none provide how to remove a package if all you have is the deb. To that end, the below command will extract the package name from the deb and remove that package name.

```
dpkg -r $(dpkg -f your-file-here.deb Package)
```

NB: this does not confirm that the package being removed is the exact *version* described by the deb - be careful.

Comment: An only correct answer. For uninstalling all *.deb files in current directory command could be something like: `for PPP in *.deb ; do sudo dpkg -r $(dpkg -f "$PPP" Package) ; done`

Comment: This should be the correct answer, especially with dess loop script.

Comment: @YodaDaCoda This was very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 10):

Open up Ubuntu Software Center *(Applications -> Ubuntu Software Center)* and search for the package you want to uninstall, and click on the *Remove* button:

[image]

Or from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove <package-name>
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `-r` with `dpkg`.

See this [**blogpost**](http://irfantechinfo.blogspot.in/2012/10/installing-uninstalling-deb-files-in.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

If your want to remove the package and all configuration files related to it:

```
sudo aptitude purge packagename
```

Answer (score 5):

### `apt-get -y` Potentially Dangerous:

Although it's true that- *sans GUI*- our choices are:

- ***apt-get remove*** (or "***purge***") *packageName*
- ***dpkg -r*** *packageName*

Where `dpkg` can be executed from a script without the equivalent of a " ***-y*** " switch, `apt` requires this to avoid user input. The consequences are that `apt` could automatically resolve package dependencies **and remove packages *other than* the target supplied to the command**.

### `apt`:

Note when I remove ***iptables*** that ***lxd*** and ***ufw***  also removed.  *But what if I didn't want **lxd** removed?* Well, it's gone now:

```
apt-get -y purge iptables
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  iptables* lxd* ubuntu-standard* ufw*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
After this operation, 23.2 MB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 90906 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-standard (1.417.3) ...
Removing ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Skip stopping firewall: ufw (not enabled)
Removing lxd (3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Removing lxd dnsmasq configuration
Removing iptables (1.6.1-2ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
(Reading database ... 90627 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Purging configuration files for lxd (3.0.3-0ubuntu1~18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.38) ...
Processing triggers for rsyslog (8.32.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
```

### `dpkg`:

Note `dpkg` stops me from potentially altering the system in an unintended way if I were to use it in a scripted execution and refusing to remove both ***ufw*** and ***lxd***:

```
dpkg -r iptables
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of iptables:
 lxd depends on iptables.
 ufw depends on iptables.

dpkg: error processing package iptables (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 iptables
```

### Conclusion:

So although it's true we like to ensure our scripts complete successfully and not exit in error, it might be desirable for a script to fail than complete by modifying the system outside of the target of the command. Such a use-case makes `dpkg -r` more desirable for scripted execution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the remove and force flags:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all pkg_name
```

Alternatively, if you installed it through Ubuntu Package Manager, you can remove it with apt:

```
$ sudo apt remove --purge pgk_name
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a user-friendly approach if you still got the .deb:

1. Double-click on .deb
2. Ubuntu Software window will open
3. Press the "Remove" button

Answer (score 2):

The installed package will be visible in both Synaptics and software center. In the former one, it will appear under local packages and in the latter one under other.

Answer (score 1):

obviously, You can use the remove and force flags:

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all    'some_bad_package'
```

but in very many cases that won't help at all. Neither will it help in case of **dpkg** breakage to try any of the GUI tools like **synaptic** or even worse ones, since they all depend on **dpkg** . This is because **dpkg** is very *opinionated* on those often-occurring errors, leaving many users marooned. Here is an example where a .deb was sideloaded and Ubuntu does not offer a GUI way nor CLI way to solve the problem:

> LANG=en sudo   dpkg --purge    'brmfc7440nlpr:i386'

> dpkg: error processing package brmfc7440nlpr:i386 (--purge):
> package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
> reinstall it before attempting a removal
> Errors were encountered while processing: brmfc7440nlpr:i386

And yes, the lead to "reinstall it before attempting..." is of course utterly futile and redundant, since it just runs into the same error with another flavour.

And yes, adding  " --force-all " just is as futile as without, obviously.

This already will lead many users to reinstall Ubuntu in hopes of betterment, taking many, many hours of extra work. The package from the real-world example above is a laserprinter (lpr) driver for a brother MFC model 7440N.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the application that you want to uninstall with below command.

```
find /usr/share/applications -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec basename {} .desktop \; | sort
```

Once you find the application name in the above list, run the below command

```
sudo apt remove your_application_name
```