# How do I uninstall Lightworks?

Tags: apt, uninstall, lightworks

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search lightworks  
lightworks - Hollywood-strength editing for everyone  
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove "lightworks - Hollywood-strength editing for everyone"  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
E: Unable to locate package lightworks - Hollywood-strength editing for everyone
```

Ubuntu Software Center can't find lightworks.

Comment: how did you install lightworks.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Syntax for removing a package with its configurations is:

```
sudo apt-get purge [Package name]
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove [Package name]
```

So run :

```
sudo apt-get purge lightworks
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove lightworks
```

The section, `Hollywood-strength editing for everyone` is a description about software. Not the package name.

Comment: it worked now. the "sudo apt-get purge lightworks" worked. i hope nothing else got effected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you manually installed lightworks from `.deb` file.

[How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)