# How to remove firefox installed from a debian package?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, firefox, uninstall, chromebook

I was having some performance issues with firefox 46 so I downgraded it to previous version by removing firefox 46 and installing from an debian package of older version firefox. Later I upgraded the firefox back to 47.  So right now the firefox on my computer is "**Mozilla Build of Firefox**". Now I want to completely remove firefox but after using `sudo apt-get purge firefox` firefox is still there. I could still open the firefox browser. Using `whereis firefox` command the following addresses are given:

`/usr/bin/firefox /etc/firefox /usr/lib/firefox /usr/bin/X11/firefox`

Please help me if you know how to completely remove the firefox browser and all the addons. My computer is really lacking spaces and any bit would help. Thank you very much.

P.S. I am using 14.04 on a Chromebook.

P.S.S This is what I got after using the purge command mentioned above:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'firefox' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link will help those who have the same problem as me: [FirefoxNewVersion](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion/MozillaBuilds)

Basically under the Uninstallation section of the document, do the following:

1. Delete the ~/firefox directory and the ~/bin/firefox file
2. Run firefox -ProfileManager and delete mozilla-build

In my case I just deleted all the firefox folders mentioned above but I don't think this is a very clean removal of **Mozilla-Build-of-Firefox**...

Answer (score 0):

Możesz You can enter the shop on ubuntu installed applications. There easily uninstall Mozilla. Or see my screena.Jest written in Polish but you should know what's going on.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shop do you mean Ubuntu Software Center? If so I have tried that option as well, but firefox is shown uninstalled on the ubuntu software center page...

Answer (score 0):

Open that deb package with either Synaptic, gdebi or Ubuntu Software Center and choose uninstall option. I prefer gdebi, as being the lightest and the fastest.

Comment: I tried the software center but the firefox was shown as not installed but it still shows up in my computer search bar... anyway I think now it is gone.. thx for your input

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Mazilla build. I was able to uninstall it with Synaptick Package Manager. I searched for "firefox" and found installed Mazilla build. Removed it, and all icons referencing build were gone. After that I was able to install the latest FF version.