# Application not shown in Ubuntu Sofware Center

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-center, dpkg

I have installed [qtmib](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qtmib/files/qtmib.deb/), SNMP MIB Browser for Ubuntu. It shown under Accessories > Internet > qtmib, but not shown in Ubuntu Sofware Center within Installed applications. Why it not shown there? How to uninstall it properly when required? Uninstalling only via terminal?

```
sudo apt-get remove packagename
```

Answer (score 1):

If you installed it manually, using some script provided or a .deb file downloaded from the Internet, and the app is not in the official repositories, the app won't be shown int the Ubuntu Software Center. To uninstall it, you can look at this thread:

[How to uninstall .deb package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)