# Application Typora not found in Dash and no Icon visible

Tags: unity-dash, search

I'm on 16.04 LTS. I've been using Typora App for Linux happily for months. Until recently, the app was easily found in the Dash by typing either "write..." or "typora...".

Installation followed the standard Ubuntu way as shown [here](https://typora.io/#linux).

However, since a couple of days, the app is not found in the dash anymore, while it still can be called from the console. If opened from the command line, there's no app icon but the default question mark.

So, how can I get Typora to behave like any other app on the Ubuntu desktop?

**Update**:

Output of `apt-cache policy typora`

```
typora:
  Installiert:           0.9.29-1
  Installationskandidat: 0.9.29-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 0.9.29-1 500
        500 https://typora.io linux/ Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.9.25-1 500
        500 https://typora.io linux/ Packages
     0.9.24-1 500
        500 https://typora.io linux/ Packages
     0.9.23-1 500
        500 https://typora.io linux/ Packages
     0.9.22-1 500
        500 https://typora.io linux/ Packages
```

Output of  `ls -l /usr/share/applications/typora.desktop /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/typora.png`

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root   302 Apr 23 18:45 /usr/share/applications/typora.desktop
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  8534 Apr 23 18:45 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/typora.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 20775 Apr 23 18:45 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/typora.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  2398 Apr 23 18:45 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/typora.png
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root  4179 Apr 23 18:45 /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/typora.png
```

**Update 2**

`unity --replace` did not bring Typora back to the Dash.

`find ~/.local/share/applications -name typora.desktop 2>&-` comes with an empty result. No file found.

Comment: For what it's worth, I think I had the same issue a couple weeks ago with Typora. My best guess is the package maintainer didn't set icons and  shortcuts up properly before releasing the .deb package for the latest version.

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy typora` and `ls -l /usr/share/applications/typora.desktop /usr/share/icons/hicolor/*/apps/typora.png`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Just added a screenshot showing the required console output

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what's too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, the application starter file and icons are all in place. Could you please try to restart Unity (`unity --replace`) just in case the application starter caches are corrupted or out of date? If that doesn't help could you please run `find ~/.local/share/applications -name typora.desktop 2>&-` and include the content of all matched files, if any, in your question? Thanks.

Comment: Do other icons appear in dash search? Also try reinstalling the package with the command `sudo apt --reinstall install typora`

Comment: Yes, other icons do appear in the Dash. I'm going to reinstall typora as suggested today.

Comment: Reinstalled the package just as adviced and everything is fine again. Problem sort of solved - but not explained :).

Answer (score -1):

The most likely reason for this is that you have accidentally deselected  applications on the filters setting for unity dash Try setting your filters as shown in the image below and searching again for typora:

[image: filters]

**Edit:** If the root cause of your issue is a packaging problem as indicated by [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912441/application-typora-not-found-in-dash-and-no-icon-visible/912570?noredirect=1#comment1435947_912441) [removing your existing package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package) and [installing the current one](https://typora.io/#linux) should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, thnx for the hint. It's not the case in my case, 'Applications' has been selected while Typora would still not appear.

Comment: @Bunjip Edited answer.

Comment: The current one is the one OP was using

Comment: @Anwar I'm sorry for any confusion you may have experienced. I don't see anything in my answer that indicates the package the OP had installed wasn't the current one. I suppose you may have misunderstood the recommendation to install the current package as an indication that the package currently installed wasn't current. If you have a better answer for the OP, by all means provide it! :-)

Comment: I understood "Installing the current one" as the latest one and it's same as the OP's. Did you mean other thing by that?

Comment: @Anwar, No  I did not.  Perhaps the confusion is mine. I thought that you were notifying me that the OP was running the current one because you thought that it was relevant to the question/answer for some reason. Again, feel free to provide a better answer. My time here will be curtailed as I'm starting a new job. :-)