# How to get the package name of .deb file?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, uninstall

I use Linux Mint which uses the same repository as Ubuntu. Recently I've installed a software from a .deb file. But, I want to uninstall it now. I know that typing the following command in terminal will do the work,

```
sudo apt remove </path/to/file_v3.31.deb>
```

But, after updating the software this method isn't working. So, I searched in the internet, I found this:

[How to uninstall a .deb package? -- Askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)

Someone answered that

> The command to facilitate that is:
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -r package_name
> ```
>
> Also if you need to remove them forcefully
>
> ```
> sudo dpkg -r --force-all pkg_name
> ```

But, how do I get this package name?

Comment: Try removing it through Ubuntu Software and also you will get its name there

Comment: Covered in https://askubuntu.com/a/1214896/158442

Comment: I think, you didn't read the whole question. :)