# How to uninstall an app, that has been downloaded from a web browser?

Tags: apt, dpkg, uninstall, deb, opera

I basically installed Opera browser from another browser, but it didn't load some videos, so I decided to download it again from Ubuntu Software and then it worked perfectly. Now I have two Opera web browsers - one from Ubuntu Software, and another one installed from a .deb file that I downloaded from another web browser. How can I uninstall the one from another browser?

I believe that I installed Opera web browser from [here](https://www.opera.com/?utm_campaign=%2300%20-%20WW%20-%20Search%20-%20EN%20-%20Branded&gclid=Cj0KCQjw1N2TBhCOARIsAGVHQc4XpR0txoU4W_jyxB-KBFH3FEljknI6xhePBwTNDiHt6YIA3HcTTScaAn-1EALw_wcB).

Comment: The one you downloaded must have some kind of "installation" script. Or did you just unpack it? Locate where the code is. It should be enough to remove the code + the .desktop file.

Comment: As above. Please [edit] the question and post the link you used. Knowing what file type it was is what we need to understand how it can be installed/uninstalled.

Comment: There is no single magic uninstall method. How you uninstall software depends upon how you originally installed it. The question as currently written provides insufficient detail about your installation to provide useful advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)

Answer (score 3):

The one you got from opera's website is a deb package (the other one is probably a snap). You should be able to uninstall it executing `sudo apt remove opera-stable` in you terminal.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: Double click downloaded .deb file & click Uninstall from graphical package manager

Following the above link, you are presented with a blue "Download" button. Clicking that button prompted me to save opera-stable_86.0.4363.50_amd64.deb. You most likely saved this file in your "Downloads" folder. Double clicking the downloaded file opera-stable_86.0.4363.50_amd64.deb should open the graphical package manager Eddy. From there, you should have the option to uninstall Opera.

[image: Eddy Package Manager showing option to uninstall or downgrade terminus-app]

Answer (score -3):

#### 1. remove opera folder

opera is installed in:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
```

to remove a folder, in this case opera

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
```

#### 2. remove /usr/bin/opera binary[command]

to know where is an app, you can start by checking with `whereis` command:

```
whereis opera
opera: /usr/bin/opera /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera
```

- `/usr/bin/opera` is where your "exe" binaries live, this is the one that makes run your app, when you type opera in terminal. if you run another command, you will notice that the opera binary is not this folder but in the one above `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera`, this is soft link, in windows,mac is known as a shortcut.

```
ll /usr/bin/opera
/usr/bin/opera -> ../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera* #returns
```

#### remove dependencies, and other stuff installed

when you install opera. it install other stuff so you can see videos or just work, in this case these are the other packages installed:

- chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
  to remove this:

```
sudo apt remove chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

#### this was the manual way

when you install apps froms browser usually is better to do it manually. but in this case you can do it with:

```
sudo apt remove opera-stable
```

and to remove dependencies and other stuff installed when you installed opera

```
sudo apt purge opera-stable
```

And even sometimes when you do this the folder created and other libraries aren't removed, this is why manually is better.