# Can't uninstall Rainlander 2

Tags: uninstall

I've installed Rainlendar2 lite from the official website in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.It is a deb package.Now,I can't uninstall it.How can I uninstall Rainlendar2 ?

Comment: How did you install it? What have you tried to uninstall it? What is the actual problem you are encountering? These are details that should be added to your question. Please edit your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to uninstall a .deb package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22200/how-to-uninstall-a-deb-package)