# Uninstall STM32CubeIDE

Tags: software-installation, software-center, uninstall, deb, software-uninstall

I downloaded and installed an older version of STM32CubeIde from this [site](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeide.html) a while ago. It is a dot DEB file version 1.5. How do I completely remove this software?
Ubuntu 20.04 is the OS used. Ubuntu Software doesn't show the installed software. Actually, my Ubuntu Software doesn't show any installed software. Thank you very much for your help.

[image]

Comment: If you know the package name, then you can [use `dpkg` to remove the application](https://askubuntu.com/a/22204/1222991) 

Comment: well that's the problem, i don't know it, i tried tab-completting 'stm' on terminal but it doesn't show up.

Comment: Can you share the deb file you used to install this software

Comment: You can download it from the site that I've shared. Just change the version to 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt purge segger-jlink-udev-rules st-stlink-server st-stlink-udev-rules st-stm32cubeide-1.5.0
```

Change the version of the last package with the one you installed 1.5.0 or 1.5.1

Comment: I purged st-stm32cubeide-1.5.0, and it works. But these two libs libpython2.7 and libpython2.7-minimal look common/important based on their names, I'm afraid to purge them, it might affect other softwares. Thank for your help Utkarsh. You are the man!

Comment: Yes you are right It might break other softwares I edited my answer , glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

From the official [installation guide](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00603964-stm32cubeide-installation-guide-stmicroelectronics.pdf):

> The uninstallation of STM32CubeIDE depends on the distribution. Uninstall STM32CubeIDE according to the step below corresponding to the distribution used:
>
> - For any distribution or if the distribution is not known:
>   `sudo /opt/st/stm32cubeide_xxxx/uninstall.sh`
> - For RPM-based distributions (such as Red Hat®, CentOS™, SUSE®, Fedora® or others): `sudo rpm -e st-stm32cubeide_xxxx st-stlink-udev-rules st-stlink-server seggerjlink-udev-rules`
> - For Debian-based distributions (such as Debian®, Ubuntu® or others): `sudo apt-get remove st-stm32cubeide-xxxx st-stlink-udev-rules st-stlink-server segger-jlink-udev-rules`

Answer (score 0):

For those who installed .sh version of cubeide can try this.

1. open terminal and write below command

user@mp-ex1:~$ cd ~

2. first find the location of installation which is "/opt/st/"

user@mp-ex1:~$ cd /opt/st/

3. view the files with list command (it will show version of cube ide you have )

user@mp-ex1:/opt/st$ ls
stm32cubeide_1.11.2

4. go inside this folder

user@mp-ex1:/opt/st$ cd stm32cubeide_1.11.2

5. list all the files

user@mp-ex1:/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.2$ ls

if you find something like uninstall.sh ,if yes then

6. run uninstaller script and press y

user@mp-ex1:/opt/st/stm32cubeide_1.11.2$ ./uninstall.sh

this process worked on one ubunto but on other there is no uninstall.sh file i think th installation method was different.